# Need a interface for a sql database as a form on django website

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, django, backbone.js

I have a django website on which i need to embed a form which is nothing but just a table interface on an SQL database. I would like to perform dynamic changes i.e. add, delete, modify etc. operations . I am not sure how I could achieve this?

I have looked on few things such as backbone js and ember and some other.

Could someone advise me which one I can use and if there any resources or examples I can look at?

Comment: Kind of like django admin interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this with Javascript and Jquery, I'm assuming you are referring to doing changes asynchronously via ajax in the client. Otherwise the standard way to do this in Django is to use the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

For async CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) I do the following:

1) Use [Django Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html) to create a RESTful HTTP interface to your models. This will ensure that you will get a POST, GET, PATCH/PUT, DELETE http urls for each operation.

2) Use jquery `$.ajax` to bind your form fields to these operations

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/yourmodel/1/',
  type: 'GET',
  accepts: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

Use a tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-et-na-us-oc-webstrhm&utm_medium=et) in your browser to test your API or alternatively you can use `curl`